# Error: class, interface, or enum expected. My code seems fine so it must be something else

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a java program which reaches out to a SQL database, however when I try to compile I get this:

```
2410_bash_scripts % ./DemoDatabase.sh
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:81: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:85: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            int[] columnWidths = new int[columnCount + 1];
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:87: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:87: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                           ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:87: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                                             ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:90: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:95: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                               ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:95: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                                                 ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:98: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                    System.out.printf(formatString, ResultSet.getObject(i));
                    ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:99: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                }
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:101: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:106: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            e.printStackTrace();
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:107: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:115: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            System.out.print("  "); //to adjust for the 4 digit IDs
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:117: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:117: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                           ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:117: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                                             ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:120: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:123: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        } catch(SQLException e)
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:126: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            e.printStackTrace();
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:127: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:130: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static void main(String[] args)
                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:136: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println(studentList);
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:138: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        System.out.println("List of all students: ");
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:139: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        for(Student s : studentList)
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:142: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:145: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:147: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static List<Student> getAllStudents()
                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:151: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:151: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                               ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:151: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                                                                                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:157: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            while(rs.next())
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:160: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:161: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:162: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                String major = rs.getString(4);
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:163: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                int gradYear = rs.getInt(5);
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:165: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                students.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, major, gradYear));
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:166: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:172: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:174: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:176: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static void printQueryResults(String... queries)
                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:178: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                               ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:178: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                                                                                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:183: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                printResults(rs);
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:184: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.println();
                ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:185: error: class, interface, or enum expected
            }
            ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:190: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:193: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static void execute(String sqlStatement)
                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:195: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                               ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:195: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
                                                                                                                                  ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:200: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java:204: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
52 errors
```

This is my code:

```
package demoDatabase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
//import java.util.*;

public class DemoDatabase
{
    private static final String databaseUrl = "jdbc:derby:FirstDatabase;create = true";

    /**
    * Prints result set
    *
    * @param ResultSet
    */
    private static void printResults(ResultSet ResultSet)
    {
        try
        {
            ResultSetMetaData metadata = ResultSet.getMetaData();

            printHeader(metadata);
            printDataSets(ResultSet, metadata);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("A problem occurred accessing the metadata");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printDataSets(ResultSet ResultSet, ResultSetMetaData metadata);
    }
        try
        {
            int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
            // create an array that stores the widths of the colums
            int[] columnWidths = new int[columnCount + 1];

            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            {
                columnWidths[i] = metadata.getColumnLabel(i).length();
            }

            //print data records in straight columns
            while(ResultSet.next())
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                {
                    String formatString = "%-" + columnWidths[i] + "s ";
                    System.out.printf(formatString, ResultSet.getObject(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("A problem occured pritung the data records.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printHeader(ResultSetMetaData metadata)
    {
        try
        {
            int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
            System.out.print("  "); //to adjust for the 4 digit IDs

            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(metadata.getColumnLabel(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        } catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("A problem occurred accessing the metadata.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // executeQuery(SqlStudent.getAll(), SqlCollege.getAll(), SqlStudentCollege.getAll(),
        //  SqlStudentCollege.getStudentNamesAndColleges);

        List<Student> studentList = getAllStudents();
        System.out.println(studentList);

        System.out.println("List of all students: ");
        for(Student s : studentList)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println("\ndone.");
    }

    public static List<Student> getAllStudents()
    {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
        {
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SqlStudent.getAll());
            // add students to list

            //add data records to list
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int id = (rs.getObject(1);
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);
                String major = rs.getString(4);
                int gradYear = rs.getInt(5);

                students.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, major, gradYear));
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return students;
    }

    public static void printQueryResults(String... queries)
    {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
        {
            for(String query : queries)
            {
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
                printResults(rs);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void execute(String sqlStatement)
    {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); Statement statement = connection.createStatement();)
        {


            statement.execute(sqlStatement);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This the bash file I am using to compile it:

```
#! #!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /.../SqlDemo # excluding my full classpath here

javac -d bin -cp lib/derby.jar src/main/java/demoDatabase/DemoDatabase.java src/main/java/demoDatabase/SqlCollege.java src/main/java/demoDatabase/SqlStudent.java src/main/java/demoDatabase/SqlStudentCollege.java
java -cp bin:lib/derby.jar demoDatabase.DemoDatabase demoDatabase.SqlCollege demoDatabase.SqlStudent demoDatabase.SqlStudentCollege
```

I have a dependency in my lib folder called derby.jar this is the database. I looked up the error and I'm pretty sure its not a curly brace. I don't even know where to start with this error since I've never gotten it before.

Comment: Which line is line 81 in the code above?

Comment: Your `printDataSets` method has an erroneous semicolon after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: And it's followed by a `}` instead of a `{`.

Comment: I would really suggest that you never claim "My code seems fine so it must be something else". That error only occurs when there is some sort of code problem, though it can be as small as one character, including a typo. Then it starts a huge chain of errors, which are cleared up when the typo is fixed.

Comment: @NomadMaker Fair enough.